# Introduce Horizontal Scroll in dropdownlist?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have a select dropdownlist which might contain long data value. I want to introduce a horizontal scroll in the select box and I am not sure if thats possible or not. Is there anyway i could introduce horizontal scroll for option elements. I want to make width of option element same as the select box.

```
<select >
  <option > [TESTLONGDATA]</option>
  <option value="ShorttData">ShorttData</option>
  <option value="Long Data">Long Data</option>
  <option value="Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data ">Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data </option>
</select>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbfFL.png

Answer (score 0):

```
       <select style="overflow:auto;max-width:50px;" >
          <option value="option1" > [TESTLONGDATA]</option>
            <option value="ShorttData">ShorttData</option>
           <option value="Long Data">Long Data</option>
           <option value="Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data ">Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data Sample Long Data                           </option>
      </select>
```

Hope above code is helpful for you.

you may increase the width by increasing the max-width

Comment: this only changes select box width, not the width of dropdown element(option element)

Comment: For that u need to go with plugins like bootstrap-multiselect

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/

Answer (score 0):

you can put class or id in the select, and add css class or id.

```
<select class="selectOption">
  <option > [TESTLONGDATA]</option>
  <option > [TESTLONGDATA]</option>
<select >
```

And put class css:

```
.selectOption { width:150px;} //Or width you want
.selectOption option { width:150px; } //Or width you want
```

Hope this can help you, thanks!